# how to import excel 2007 file containing 0.4 million records into mysql table

Tags: mysql, excel

how to import excel 2007 file containing 0.4 million records into mysql table ? please suggest

appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) export to csv

2) use mysqlimport against csv file.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html

from above, win32 instrux:

```
mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=""" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv
```